# Writing Mouse Click X and Y to console

Tags: vb.net, click, mouse

I am trying to write a program that needs to find the X and Y of a mouse click so I wrote this little Debug Code

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick

  Console.WriteLine(ToString(e.X) + "," + ToString(e.Y))

End Sub
```

When I run it I get the error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe` I don't see how my code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice VB.NET trap, induced by () meaning so many things.  In this case, it is an *indexing expression*.  You are actually calling the form's ToString() method, in other words Me.ToString() and that returns a string like "WindowsApplication1.Form1".  Using `(x)` on a string is valid syntax, it returns the character at position x.  Works when you keep the mouse in the far upper left corner, you get something like `W,W` :)  But move the mouse and it goes Kaboom! when you index a position in the string that's beyond the string length.

Fix with:

```
 Console.WriteLine(e.X.ToString() + "," + e.Y.ToString())
```

or:

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", e.X, e.Y)
```

or:

```
 Console.WriteLine(e.Location)
```

or the more sane:

```
 Label1.Text = e.Location.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dose it compile?
Change the line

```
Console.WriteLine(ToString(e.X) + "," + ToString(e.Y))
```

To

```
Console.WriteLine(e.X.ToString() + "," + e.Y.ToString())
```

Comment: It compiled before but threw that error when it tried to run. It works now. I don't see the difference between the first and second lines of code, shouldn't they be doing exactly the same thing?

Comment: @RX14 as per documentation both Convert.ToString() and Object.ToString() do the same thing.